# Sort or Reverse list in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I tried to reverse or sort list in robot framework but None has returned for both sort/reverse

```
    @{list1}    create list  Hello  World  143  Ok  lets  lets see
    log to console    ${list1}
    ${list2}    reverse list    ${list1}
    log to console    Reverse list is ${list2}



    ['Hello', 'World', '143', 'Ok', 'lets', 'lets see']
    Reverse list is None
   | PASS |
```

Answer (score 3):

Both keywords [do the operation in-place](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Reverse%20List), modifying the original list. Don't assign a variable to their returned value, as they return nothing - and the var becomes a None.

Just use the original list after the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Just change two rows to:

```
reverse list    ${list1}
log to console    Reverse list is ${list1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse List:- Reverses the given list in place.

Note that the given list is changed and nothing is returned

```
@{list1}    create list  Hello  World  143  Ok  lets  lets see
  log to console    ${list1}
  reverse list    ${list1}
  log to console    Reverse list is ${list1}
```

output:-
['Hello', 'World', '143', 'Ok', 'lets', 'lets see']

..Reverse list is ['lets see', 'lets', 'Ok', '143', 'World', 'Hello']

Similarly with sort list too...

```
@{list1}    create list  Hello  World  143  Ok  lets  lets see
  log to console    ${list1}
  sort list    ${list1}
  log to console    sort list is ${list1}
```

['Hello', 'World', '143', 'Ok', 'lets', 'lets see']

sort list is ['143', 'Hello', 'Ok', 'World', 'lets', 'lets see']

Comment: Similarly with sort list too...
@{list1}    create list  Hello  World  143  Ok  lets  lets see

  log to console    ${list1}

  sort list    ${list1}

  log to console    sort list is ${list1}